# Number of characters in each word of sentence

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split, count

I want to develop a code that counts the number of characters of each word in a sentence and test if it is between 2 and 14 characters.

If it is between 2 and 14 characters then result1 = true

otherwise result1 = false

here is my code:

```js
var sentence = "Now is the time for all men"
var re = /\s+/;
var resultat1 = false;
var nameList = sentence.split(re); //cutting the sentence into words
console.log(nameList);               //List of words in the sentence
var NbMot = nameList.length; //Number of words in the sentence
var NbCarMot = 0; //Numer of caracter in each word
for (i = 0; i < NbMot; i++) {
  NbCarMot = (nameList[i].length); //Numer of caracter in each word
  console.log(NbCarMot);
}
console.log(NbCarMot);
if (NbCarMot <= 14) {
  resultat1 = true;
}
console.log(resultat1)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: I created you a snippet - we really want a [mcve] and a description of expected and actual output

Comment: Do you want to ensure *all* words are between 2-14, or just that at least one word is between 2-14?

Comment: Not to mention a fake profile pic

Comment: my problem is that code don't return the result that i want

Comment: @@musefan : all words are between 2-14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sentence = 'hello Good morning';
var resultat1 = true;
var re = /\s+/;
var nameList = sentence.split(re);    //cutting the sentence into words

for (i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
    var len = nameList[i].length; //Numer of caracter in each word
    if (len < 2 || len > 14)     //Test your counts
    {
        resultat1 = false; // if not match set variable to false and break
        break;
    }
}

alert(resultat1); // check your final result
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to develop a code that counts the number of characters of each
>   word in a sentence and test if it is between 2 and 14 characters,

You need to break out of the loop as soon as first violation of your rule ***(between 2 and 14 characters)*** is found.

Try this simple one using `some`

```
var isInvalid = sentence.split( /\s+/ ).some( s => s.length < 2 || s.length > 14 );
```